# Will I have to pay VAT or other taxes when paying an article processing charge from India?

Tags: publications, open-access

Recently my manuscript has been accepted in Nature Scientific Reports, an open access journal.

They charge £1,110 to the UK and other countries.

Will additional tax be added when transferring the article processing charge to the journal's account? And if so, how much?

Comment: VAT is a local tax, and its amount depends in this case on the Indian law, not the UK's.

Comment: When I last payed such a charge, I had to provide the publisher with our VAT ID.